# Regarding producers and consumer pattern in java with blocking queue approach

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I was doing a research in producers and consumer design patterns with regards to threads in java, I recently explored in java 5 with the introduction With introduction of BlockingQueue Data Structure in Java 5 Its now much simpler because BlockingQueue provides this control implicitly by introducing blocking methods put() and take(). Now you don't require to use wait and notify to communicate between Producer and Consumer. BlockingQueue put() method will block if Queue is full in case of Bounded Queue and take() will block if Queue is empty. In next section we will see a code example of Producer Consumer design pattern. I have developed the below program but please also let me know the old style approach of waut() and notify() , I want to develop the same logic with old style approach also

Folks please advise how this can be implemented in , classical way is using wait() and notify() method to communicate between Producer and Consumer thread and blocking each of them on individual condition like full queue and empty queue...?

```
    import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ProducerConsumerPattern {

    public static void main(String args[]){

     //Creating shared object
     BlockingQueue sharedQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue();

     //Creating Producer and Consumer Thread
     Thread prodThread = new Thread(new Producer(sharedQueue));
     Thread consThread = new Thread(new Consumer(sharedQueue));

     //Starting producer and Consumer thread
     prodThread.start();
     consThread.start();
    }

}

//Producer Class in java
class Producer implements Runnable {

    private final BlockingQueue sharedQueue;

    public Producer(BlockingQueue sharedQueue) {
        this.sharedQueue = sharedQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            try {
                System.out.println("Produced: " + i);
                sharedQueue.put(i);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Producer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

}

//Consumer Class in Java
class Consumer implements Runnable{

    private final BlockingQueue sharedQueue;

    public Consumer (BlockingQueue sharedQueue) {
        this.sharedQueue = sharedQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            try {
                System.out.println("Consumed: "+ sharedQueue.take());
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Consumer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }


}

Output:
Produced: 0
Produced: 1
Consumed: 0
Produced: 2
Consumed: 1
Produced: 3
Consumed: 2
Produced: 4
Consumed: 3
Produced: 5
Consumed: 4
Produced: 6
Consumed: 5
Produced: 7
Consumed: 6
Produced: 8
Consumed: 7
Produced: 9
Consumed: 8
Consumed: 9
```

Comment: What is the question? Is it part of homework?

Comment: BlockingQueue was introduced into Java 5.0, 8 years ago but it was a separate library much longer than that. I don't imagine people using wait/notify to do what you suggest in fact I wouldn't use a BlockingQueue at all, you should be using an ExecutorService.

Comment: @PeterLawrey,is there any advantage using ExecutorService instead of BlokingQueue?

Comment: @PeterLawrey that's great man, thanks for advise could you please post how to achieve this same thing with execotor service also . that will make understanding more clear..!1

Comment: @UVM yeah peter please also share this..!1

Comment: An ExecutorService wraps a Queue and a thread pool (which can be single, fixed or cached). When you submit tasks to it, you can obtain a Future which will give you the result or exception when its available, you can shutdown the whole thing with one method call. It also support scheduled and periodic recurring events

Comment: @PeterLawrey cool man , But if you can please update the code in post that will make understanding more clear still it is as much not clear , please update the post with the code as I have shown to make understandings absolutely clear..!that will be a great help..!!

Comment: @user1583868 I have added an alternative using an answer. I hope you can see its simpler. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can do this wait-notify stuff in my sleep (or at least I think I can).  Java 1.4 source provided beautiful examples of all this, but they've switched to doing everything with atomics and it's a lot more complicated now.  The wait-notify does provide flexibility and power, though the other methods can shield you from the dangers of concurrency and make for simpler code.

To do this, you want some fields, like so:

```
private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Intger>  sharedQueue =
                                                    new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
private volatile   boolean  waitFlag = true;
```

Your Producer.run would look like this:

```
public void run()  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000, i++)  {
        System.out.println( "Produced: " + i );
        sharedQueue.add( new Integer( i ) );
        if (waitFlag)       // volatile access is cheaper than synch.
            synchronized (sharedQueue)  { sharedQueue.notifyAll(); }
    }
}
```

And Consumer.run:

```
public void run()  {
    waitFlag = false;
    for (;;)  {
        Integer  ic = sharedQueue.poll();
        if (ic == null)  {
            synchronized (sharedQueue)  {
                waitFlag = true;
                // An add might have come through before waitFlag was set.
                ic = sharedQueue.poll();
                if (ic == null)  {
                    try  { sharedQueue.wait(); }
                    catch (InterruptedException ex)  {}
                    waitFlag = false;
                    continue;
                }
                waitFlag = true;
            }
        }
        System.out.println( "Consumed: " + ic );
    }
}
```

This keeps synchronizing to a minimum.  If all goes well, there's only one look at a volatile field per add.  You should be able to run any number of producers simultaneously.  (Consumer's would be trickier--you'd have to give up `waitFlag`.) You could use a different object for wait/notifyAll.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to know another way to do this try using an ExecutorService

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        System.out.println("Produced: " + i);

        final int finalI = i;
        service.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Consumed: " + finalI);
            }
        });
    }
    service.shutdown();
}
```

With just 10 tasks the producer can be finished before the consumer starts. If you try 100 tasks you may find them interleaved.

Comment: cool man this make the understanding clear now but please advise will it work with jdk1.5 also..?

Comment: for 100 tasks could you explain once again and also what if I in the above code I don't wish to go for annoynous inner class with executor service then how will be the code..

Comment: ExecutorService was added in Java 5.0.  I wouldn't suggest you use Java 5.0 if possible and even avoid Java 6 as it will be end of support this year.  Try using Java 7 instead.

Comment: @user1583868 If you didn't want to use an anonymous inner class you can refactor it to be a nested or package local or top level class. In my IDE there is a hot key to move the class so you don't need to know how to code it as such. ;)

Comment: @user1583868 I prefer to be able to see all the important code in one place so you can see everything it does without having to jump around the code or remember too much. ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to understand how a BlockingQueue works, for educational purposes, you can always have a look on [its source code](http://kickjava.com/src/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.java.htm).

The simplest way could be to `synchronize` the `offer()` and `take()` methods, and once the queue is full and someone is trying to `offer()` an element - invoke `wait()`. When someone is taking an element, `notify()` the sleeping thread. (Same idea when trying to `take()` from an empty queue).

Remember to make sure all your `wait()` calls are nested in loops that checks if the conditions are met each time the thread is awakened.

If you are planning to implement it from scratch for product purposes - I'd strongly argue against it. You should use an existing, tested libraries and components as much as possible.

Comment: Small note: The source code does not implement the "simplest way" as I described - simply because it is not efficient, the described implementation prevents from two threads to take/offer elements concurrently, while for most cases - it could be done.

Comment: could you also please update the code in the post as I have done that will make understanding more clear..!