# Creating Dice game in java using Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I want to provide implementation of a 4 player dice game in which each player is implemented as a thread . Each player get a chance to throw the dice in order of player number . each throw dies return a number 1 to 6 only . the game stop whenever any player scores 25 point or more print winner player .

I am Thinking of creating classes

**Dice** for handling Dice

**Board** For handling all Thread and Player Score

**TheGame**  for Starting game

*My class Dice*

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Dice {
Random dice;
public Dice()
{
dice=new Random();
}

public int throwDice()
{
    int a= dice.nextInt(70);
    a=a/10;
    if (a==0)
        return 1;
    else return a;
}
```

}

*My Player Class*

```
public class Player extends Thread {
Board board;
int num;
public Player(Board b,int n)
{
board=b;
num=n;
}
public void run()
{
System.out.println("Player "+num+" is started, playing game...");
while(board.flag)
{
board.play(num);    
}
}
}
```

*Game Class*

```
public class TheGame {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Initializing board...");
        Board b=new Board();  //Creating object of class board
        System.out.println("Initializing players...");
        Player p1=new Player(b,1); // Every player is Thread
        Player p2=new Player(b,2);
        Player p3=new Player(b,3);
        Player p4=new Player(b,4);
        p1.start(); //Starting Thread
        p3.start();
        p2.start();
        p4.start();
    }

}
```

I am not able to think Logic or decide where to start in class Board. 
Please Help me with Board code

This is not assignment or homework .
I want to do it by myself but don't have any deep idea about Synchronization in Threading

I am trying to code i am not asking complete tutorials i am just asking how do i set order when player 1(thread) get execute after player 1 have done his chance.

Comment: While I do think experimenting and learning with threading is a good idea, I just want to make sure you're aware that you shouldn't implement a dice game of this type with threading for production code.

Comment: @hexafraction Thanks, I just want to dig in threading , but my tutor once told me threading mostly use in making game like this . so i think of implementing this

Comment: If your tutor told you to use multithreading in a text-based dice game I'd find a new tutor.

Comment: @hexafraction I just want to give a try with that .Please if you help that't would be great

Comment: It's relatively difficult to put a full threading tutorial in an answer. I suggest [the Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) and asking when you have a specific question.

Comment: @hexafraction: I have knowledege of creating thread . Simply i want to know which logic do i implement on this .

Comment: You'll need synchronization logic. Read more of the tutorial or rephrase your question to be more specific.

Comment: Voting to close question as being too broad. You're really asking for a complete tutorial here, and there are tutorials already available for your review. You just have to do it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i edited my question.i think that would be helpful .

Comment: I added code and More Details to My question Hope it will get Open again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just to point you in the right direction.  You need to read a lot more than I can ever write here.  Then you need to to fix all manner of weird and irreproducable bugs.  But you did ask...

I think it's a lot simpler, and more interesting, if all 4 players throw at once.  (Though you might have more than one winner.)  To do that:

Create global monitors and field (Perhaps in Game class):

```
public static final turnMonitor = new Object();
public static final controlMonitor = new Object();
public static volatile gameOn = true;
```

Then create a Player class with a run method.  (Player can extend Thread, or it can extend Runnable and you can pass it to a new Thread.)  Like so:

```
public void run()  {
    while (gameOn)  {
        synchronized (turnMonitor)  { turnMonitor.wait(); }
        ...roll dice here...
        ...Put sum of Player rolls in volatile instance field or synched field...
        ...Update volatile player turn counter...
        synchronized (controlMonitor)  {
            // Tell control monitor we're done.
            controlMonitor.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you'll want control code (in the Game class?):

```
while (true)  {
    // Roll dice
    synchronized (turnMonitor)  { turnMonitor.notifyAll(); }
    // Wait for dice to roll
    do  {
        synchronized (controlMonitor)  { controlMonitor.wait(); }
    }  while ( ...not all players have rolled this turn... );
    if ( there's a winner )  break;
}
gameOn = false;
```

This should give you a start.  Do study up on synchronization, volatiles, wait(), and notifyAll().  If you can't find *good* examples anywhere, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11972367/796401) (for the very basics).

When starting, print lots of debugging messages.  Threads are always running when you're not expecting them to.  You *are* going to be surprised.

To have the players roll one at a time, I think you'd want multiple turn monitors.  You can notify only one waiting thread at a time, but you can't control *which* thread gets notified, so trying get the right thread off one monitor would be difficult.

Comment: Thanls a lot , It will help me a lot thanks .